# GWT RequestBuilder

Tags: gwt, xmlhttprequest

How do i use GWT Request builder to pass on a String from my GWT code  to a website www.xyz.com.It would be greatly helpful if i can get the code for doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make cross-domain XHR requests, you need to use [`JsonpRequestBuilder`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/jsonp/client/JsonpRequestBuilder.java?r=5225), which is pretty well documented in its comments.

Feel free to ask a more specific question if you encounter any specific problems.

Comment: i dont want to use the JsopP stuff.Is there any other way by which  i can do it?My only requirement is to send a string to www.xyz.com.I dont want any information back into my application.I suppose i can use request builder for this.Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: If you just want to send a string to the server you could load an image with src="yourserver.com?msg=hello+world" and handle that request on your server. Just make sure your image is invisible or else it will appear as a broken image.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to just send a string, then you can do something simple like add an `Image`/`<img>` with `src` pointing to `www.xyz.com` + the string you want to send - the src won't be pointing to an image actually (of course), it's just that you can sidestep SOP (Same Origin Policy). Of course, you have to handle the requests for "the image" appropriately on `www.xyz.com` (and make sure the broken image is hidden/not shown on the client side).
Anyway, that's the basic idea - a `<script>` tag would work too.